# If there a reliable way to identify an email message as a forward?

Tags: email, email-headers

I think the answer is no, but I thought I'd ask in case someone knows better.

The application I work on accepts incoming email, I'm trying to find a way to identify a message as having been forwarded (not server-side forwarding, just a regular old "I want to forward this email message"), so I can identify the original sender address (and hopefully then the content).

I do see any indication I can do this via the email headers, leaving me with parsing subject and body for clues, which would be very inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look for the `X-Forwarded-For` header (which applies to HTML as well as email)

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For):

```
X-Forwarded-For is also an email-header indicating that an email-message was forwarded from one or more other accounts (probably automatic).
```

Comment: I believe that is only for a more automatic server-side forwarding. I just mean like when you read an email and then hit the "forward" button in your client. I don't see the X-Forwarded-For header when I do that sort of forwarding.